# Unable to sync a repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, memory

```
From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/llvm                                                             
 * [new tag]         android-7.1.2_r17 -> android-7.1.2_r17                                                              
Fetching project LineageOS/android_packages_providers_MediaProvider                                                      
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/libogg                                                                             
warn: --force-broken, continuing to sync                                                                                 
Fetching projects:  90% (514/571)  Fetching project LineageOS/android_external_rsync                                     
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/eclipse-windowbuilder (GitError: fetch: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory)         
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                       
  File "/root/viperland/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>                                                       
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])                                                                                                  
  File "/root/viperland/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main                                                          
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0                                                                                        
  File "/root/viperland/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run                                                           
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)                                                                                   
  File "/root/viperland/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 781, in Execute                                                
    fetched = self._Fetch(to_fetch, opt)                                                                                 
  File "/root/viperland/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 379, in _Fetch                                                 
    t.start()                                                                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 745, in start                                                             
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())                                                                              
thread.error: can't start new thread                                                                                     
Segmentation fault
```

I left my server to download the source of VIPEROS overnight but when I woke up, I saw this error.

Comment: please format edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's a memory issue. Same as here:

https://discuss.96boards.org/t/repo-sync-issues/602/2

Comment: how much ram is recommended? Is 6-8GB ram enough?